# Multiple $http calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

So here is what I need to do. I'm using the [Angular Deferred Bootstrap](https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap) library in my code because I need to receive some essential data from a RESTful server before bootstrapping and trying to load the content. Anyway, I must make a second call once the first call resolves. The second call is a login that depends on some URL that is contained in the first response.

Right now, I want to try to make the login call once I receive that data (I was trying in the .success() block) but once the first call resolves, the program begins bootstrapping before the login call is finished; things break because I'm not "logged in" on the server.

```
window.deferredBootstrapper.bootstrap({
                element: window.document.body,
                module: 'app',
                resolve: {
                    STARTUP_CONFIG: ['$http', function($http) {
                        return $http.get(url1 + 'blah/blah/blah/' + layout);
                    }],

                    CONTEXT_CONFIG: ['$http', function($http) {
                        return $http.get(url1 + 'blah/blah/blah/blah').
                        success(function(data) {
                            $http.post('https://' + data.url2 + '/10001/guestidentity?client_id=' + data.id).
                            success(function(result){
                                token = result.token;
                            });
                        });
                    }],
                }
            });
```

Anyone have any idea what I can do?

Comment: `but once the first call resolves, it returns the resolved promise before the login call is finished` uh.... no... it returns the unresolved promise immediately, then when it becomes resolved, the second one starts.

Comment: What I meant was that the Deferred Bootstrap library prevents my app from bootstrapping until the promise resolves.

Comment: The issue is you're returning a promise that represents the first $http rather than the second. You don't really care when the first resolves because you want it to continue after the second resolves, not the first. Dayan's answer handles that.

Comment: But I do care when the first resolves because I cannot make the second call without the data I receive from the first.

Comment: well, of course, but you don't need the bootstrap to know that.

Comment: I need to prevent the bootstrap until I have the necessary token from the login, or else I'm denied further access to the api when the app bootstraps and tries to make unauthorized calls to the api. Maybe I was unclear about that in my original post, but I need it to wait until both of those calls are resolved and the necessary data stored. Cause regardless, its still failing with the .then() block.

Comment: No, you're perfectly clear. I think we are saying the same thing. You want the bootstrap to wait until the login success runs, which should be accomplished by using .then. .then allows you to return the promise from the second $http rather than the first.

Comment: It's throwing an error in the console that shows the variables as undefined eg:// 'https://undefined/blah/blah/blah/undefined'

Comment: that doesn't tell me anything. .then should solve your problem, at this point i'm assuming your problem is elsewhere

Comment: The only error I'm getting just says ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED because the url is incorrect with the undefined variables. How would I use $q? I have a lot of trouble understanding deferred promises.

Comment: you don't need $q, sorry. That was me not understanding how $http was built, now i understand it. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.2/src/ng/http.js#L673 my guess is the issue is coming from how you are generating the url (which isn't shown in your question)

Comment: First, thanks for sticking with me here. All I'm doing is concatenating data from the first call (which are just parts of the url that can change) with a static string (always part of the url). The URL is perfectly fine and the call succeeds when it is in a .success() block. But the problem with putting it in the success block is that then the program bootstraps before I receive a token. So it's not how I'm generating the URL that is the issue. .then() seems to be executing right away.

Comment: switch back to .success, and return the $http inside it just like you would with .then. Note, if it works with success, then the whole problem was you simply werent using the argument from .then correctly. (it isn't the same as .success)

Comment: The deferred bootstrap library now complains that I'm not returning a promise: "Uncaught Error: Resolve function for 'CONTEXT_CONFIG' must return a promise."

Comment: you didn't return the token did you? that would not be a promise

Comment: No: "return $http.post('https://' + data.url2 + '/10001/guestidentity?client_id=' + data.id).success(function(result){
                                token = result.token;
                            });"

Comment: So I just added a $timeout of 2000 to force it to wait long enough for a resolve and return the promise manually after storing it in a variable. It works fine, so for some reason it's not waiting for the inner call to resolve still :/

Comment: I see why. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L673 the return isn't being returned to the inner .then. That means you will have to use .then. :) Note that you'll have to use result.data rather than just using result directly.

Comment: Dayan's answer does explain this in comments within the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi since this is a promise you can chain the next call to the then function something like

```
  $http(url).
  then(function(response){
           //note that this shouldn't be the body of the response
           // but the entire response stream so you need to check for the status code and the body and apply and possibly apply any transformation that is needed as it will probably be just text
             // then we can start the other call
             return $http(url); 
   })
```

this way the second promise will be handled to the final destination.

Comment: he shouldn't have to do any transformations other than using `response.data.token` rather than `response.token`